# Changes on @Input array not detected on child

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following angular2 parent:

```
ParentComponent {

   some_array : Array;

   (...)

}
```

And its child:

```
ChildComponent {

     selector: "child"
     @Input some_object : Object;

}
```

My layout is as follows, from the Parent component:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let object of some_array">
     <child [some_object]="object></child>
</ng-container>
```

And Child layout:

```
<Text [text]="some_object.text"/>
```

**The view is rendered accordingly and works perfectly**.

However, when I change my object property inside `some_array` in the parent element via a for loop with [i]ndex, nothing changes in the child element and I need to detect these changes.

How exactly could I do this?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Please create a demo that showcases this issue :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you haven't actually chosen OnPush as the ChangeDetectionStrategy or detached from ChangeDetection completely, the changes should replicate in your child.

However if you question is how you generally can react to changes of data-bound properties, there is the `OnChanges` lifecycle hook.

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {

   ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

     if (changes['some_object']) {
       //
       // react to changes in general
       // or access changes['some_object'].currentValue
       // or changes['some_object'].previousValue
       // ...
     }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps to resolve your issue!